# How to run a program under different user's accounts?

Tags: windows, user-accounts, uac

My program `C:\Program Files\MyApp\Myprog` starts with Windows startup; at device insertion **Myprog.exe** invokes another program `C:\Windows\comp.exe`. 
This process works fine in the admin account in which I install the programs but **Myprog.exe** is unable to invoke **comp.exe** when users account is changed. 
I want `C:\Windows\comp.exe` to be invoke in each type of account e.g admin group accounts and non-admin accounts. Please help 
P.S both programs are not UAC patched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your exec-command inside the your application you could use the Windows built-in command **runas**.

For example:

**runas** /noprofile /user:mymachine\administrator "C:\Program Files\MyApp\Myprog.exe"

(you can probably omit the domain mymachine\ in your environment)

---

A different solution would be to make the comparison in a temporary directory with full access to the user, since it seams you try to do this in a protected directory on he system drive. - Maybe in the user's home.

Unfortunately I know nothing about "Myprog". But maybe you forgot to set the working directory of "comp.exe" so it tries to run inside C:\Windows which is of course protected from non-administrators.

---

[runas reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525.aspx)
[same problem, solution with a batch file](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/419-run-different-user.html)

Comment: How to specify password from command line? Or it is not required?

Comment: You can use runas' /savecred flag in order to save the credentials of the other user to your account.